# Spring Integration Message<Payload> vs Payload as output parameter

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring integration flow which contains a jdbc outbound gateway with a `select query SELECT * FROM  Users WHERE userId=:payload`
Initially my gateway method was like

```
public List<UserBO> findUser(String userId);
```

I have row mapper that maps data from sql result to a UserBO object.
In the above case I was always getting a list of users even if there is 1 or more rows in the sql result set.

I have changed the gateway method to

```
public Message<List<UserBO>> findUser(String userId);
```

since I need a header value from the message.
Now the problem is when there are 2 or more rows in the sql result set my payload in returned message is list of user objects. But if there is only a single row in the sql result set, the payload is a UserBO object; not the list of userBO objects.

So I need to check the instance of pay load before processing the response message.
Is this an expected behavior from Spring integration?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please, share your configuration and Spring Integration version. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! I see. The problem is around `ConversionService`.

All components in Spring Integration accepts `Message<?>` and returns `Message<?>` independently of you parameters extraction.

That's first fact.

The second: `JdbcOutboundGateway` has a code:

```
if (list.size() == 1) {
    payload = list.get(0);
}
return this.getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(payload).copyHeaders(requestMessage.getHeaders()).build();
```

As you see it returns `Message<?>` as we talked before, but notice which `payload` it has.

The next fact in the chain.

You gateway's method has signature:

```
public Message<List<UserBO>> findUser(String userId);
```

So, return a `Message<?>`! Since we already have a message from the `JdbcOutboundGateway` reply, there is no need to take care about `payload` *conversion*. And voila! you want to get `Message<List<UserBO>>`, but it is just `Message<UserBO>`, because of that `JdbcOutboundGateway` logic.

Since generics is a compile-time feature we can simply cast the last one to the first one, but than we get `ClassCastException` when we try to extract and cast `payload` from it.

The first case works well, because we extract your single `UserBO` `payload` from the reply message and send it to the `ConversionService` to convert to `List<UserBO>` as your first variant requires.

In this case it can simply instantiate a `Collection` for us and populates our single object there.

Nothing to do for that `Message<T>` case. Because we won't be able to extract the generic type from there. Or even better we don't want to do that. Because exactly this communication with `Message` objects allow us to bypass that `ConversionService` and get better performance and throughput.

Hope I am clear.